# How to define an app as a new version for an existing one

Tags: android, google-play, apk, version

I’m very much an Android Studio newbie who is updating an old app that was originally developed using Eclipse.

I decided to start from scratch as far as naming was concerned, choosing a different project name, different package names, etc. This turns out to have been a poor decision – well, not exactly a decision, as not much thought was put into it. But now, when I create an apk to install on my phone for testing, it gets installed alongside the original app and is not seen as a replacement version.

So, what are the important properties of the app that I need to change to have the system see it as a replacement for the original?

Answer (score 0):

The `applicationId`, located into the `build.gradle` file should be the same as your old app otherwise it will identified as a different app.
For instance:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        applicationId "com.yourcompany.yourapp"
    } 
}
```

Indeed, the `versionCode` should be greater than the one set on your old app.

If you need to check which is the `applicationId` of your old app, just install it and use the following adb command:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

to list of the `applicationIds` that refers to the installed apps. With that on hand it should be quite straightforward to identify your old app.

Comment: The applicationId has to be set to the packageName of the old app.

Comment: When I do that, the imports for the R class fail because the name has changed. Do I have to rename all the packages to match?